# Flask-SQLAlchemy: Automatic filter for 'deleted' entries

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a huge code base that does all database interactions as following:

```
ExampleClass.query.all()
```

Where the `ExampleClass` inherits the properties of `db.Model` and our `BaseEntity` defined as following:

```
class BaseEntity(object):
    deleted = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=None, nullable=True)
    ... # more columns
```

Now when i query the `ExampleClass` for all entries, `ExampleClass.query.all()`, i want the entries where the deleted field is set to a date, aka the entry is removed from the system to be excluded. It would be ideal if i wouldn't have to update the entire codebase with a simple `.filter(deleted != None)`. My solution for this was adding a SQLAlchemy event filter: [`before_compile`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/events.html?highlight=before_compile#sqlalchemy.orm.events.QueryEvents.before_compile). The documentation gave me exactly what is was searching for:

```
@event.listens_for(Query, "before_compile", retval=True)
def no_deleted(query):
    for desc in query.column_descriptions:
        if desc['type'] is ExampleClass:
            entity = desc['expr']
            query = query.filter(entity.deleted == False)
    return query
```

However i cannot get this to work, the last error i got stuck on is as following:

```
AttributeError: 'Mapper' object has no attribute 'deleted'
```

Versions of the libraries I use are: Flask==0.10.1, Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0, SQLAlchemy==1.0.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it is old question, but recently I make it work by this function:

```
@event.listens_for(Query, "before_compile", retval=True) 
def no_deleted(query):
    for desc in query.column_descriptions:
        if desc['type'] is ExampleClass:
           entity = desc['entity']

           limit, offset = query._limit, query._offset
           query._limit, query._offset = None, None

           query = query.filter(entity.deleted == False)

           query._limit, query._offset = limit, offset

    return query
```

You need to do the filter on entity, not type. And temporary remove limit and offset.

Flask==1.0.2, Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2, SQLAlchemy==1.2.12

[link to sqlalchemy docs for this event](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.QueryEvents.before_compile)

### Upgraded version:

if you want to be able to not exclude deleted items there is this option:

Create QueryMixin:

```
class ShowDeleted:
    def show_deleted(self):
        q = self._clone()
        q.__dict__['__show_deleted'] = True
        return q
```

edit no_deleted function

```
def no_deleted(query):
    for desc in query.column_descriptions:
        show_deleted = query.__dict__.get('__show_deleted', False)
        if not show_deleted and desc['type'] is ExampleClass:
            entity = desc['entity']

            limit, offset = query._limit, query._offset
            query._limit, query._offset = None, None

            query = query.filter(entity.deleted == False)

            query._limit, query._offset = limit, offset

    return query
```

and if you are using FlaskSQLAlchemy, setup db this way:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, BaseQuery

db = SQLAlchemy(query_class= type('Query', (ShowDeleted, BaseQuery), {}))
```

in case of raw sqlalchemy use this snippet:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(query_cls=type('Query', (ShowDeleted, Query), {})))
```

now you can in your code call

```
db.session.query(ExampleClass).show_deleted().all()
```

Comment: This works great. But what to do, when I want to apply my "show_deleted() attribute" also to all relationships within my object model?
So when I call "db.session.query(Parent).show_deleted().all()", to get also all deleted Children configured via "db.relationship(Child)" in Parent model class.

Answer (score -1):

The obvious and easy approach to do this (tested and works for me) would be:

```
class BaseEntity(db.Model):
    deleted = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=None, nullable=True)

BaseEntity.query = BaseEntity.query.filter(BaseEntity.deleted == None)
```

That said, other developers might expect that `BaseEntity.query` starts with a clean query object so you might consider using a different class property than `query`:

```
class BaseEntity(db.Model):
    deleted = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=None, nullable=True)

BaseEntity.non_deleted = BaseEntity.query.filter(BaseQuery.deleted == None)

# and then use it like …
BaseEntity.non_deleted.all()
```